# Truncated random variable also converges

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Assuming $X_n\to X$ almost surely then I need to show $X_n\mathbb1_{|X_n|<r}\to X\mathbb1_{|X|<r}$ almost surely for all but countably many $r\in(0,\infty)$

I don't get for which $r$ should this fail to converge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for instance $X_n := 1-\frac{1}{n}$, $X=1$ and $r=1$. Then $X_n \to X$ almost surely but $X_n 1_{\{|X_n|<1\}} \to X 1_{\{|X|<1\}}$ fails to hold.

Comment: Yeah. but what is sufficient to ensure that it works except for countably many $r$'s ? for example is $EX_n,EX<\infty$ enough ?

Comment: @counterfeit You were just asking why convergence can fail... and not for sufficient conditions. Anyway, as far i can see, you don't need additional assumptions. Check that there are at most countably many $r$ with $\mathbb{P}(|X|=r)>0$ and then show that almost sure convergence holds for all other $r$